# Cloudflare SSL/TLS encryption mode

Tags: apache, xampp, cloudflare

I have set the setting in cloudflare ssl/tls to Full (strict), but my server is connecting even with a self certificate. Why is this? My server is configured with Apache.

I want to prevent access to servers with self certificates.

Answer (score 0):

If you set ssl/tls to Full, you will force CF to redirect traffic over ssl/tls. If your server is using a self-signed certificate you will need to upload a valid cert.

To avoid direct access, you need to set up authentication origin pull:
https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/origin-configuration/authenticated-origin-pull/explanation/
so that all traffic is evaluated before receiving a response from your server.

If you want your server to stop using self-signed certs, you can download a valid one from CF, and load it:
https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/origin-configuration/origin-ca/